# How to maximize SEO of an internationalized website?

Tags: internationalization, seo

I am developing a website that should be multi languages.

I would like your opinions about what the best way to do it, considering get the most SEO possible.

I have these alternatives:

**Altarnative 1:** Separate domains

```
http://www.miweb.com -- English for default
http://www.miweb.com.fr
http://www.miweb.com.es
http://www.miweb.com.it
```

**Altarnative 2:** Sub domains

```
http://www.miweb.com -- English for default
http://fr.miweb.com
http://es.miweb.com
http://it.miweb.com
```

**Altarnative 3:** Sub folders

```
http://www.miweb.com -- English for default
http://www.miweb.com/fr
http://www.miweb.com/es
http://www.miweb.com/it
```

I would like to know about your experiences.
I hope the question is okay.

Any suggestions, comments, objections or idea is welcome. Thank you.

Comment: this is better suitable for [Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com) ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no perfect recipe for SEO analysis. It will always be a unique experience, based on the website, the market, the brand, the competitors and the problems being worked on, as well as the technology in question, but there is a good post on [Google Webmaster Central](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2010/03/working-with-multi-regional-websites.html) about this subject, but **here are some of the possible URL structures with pros and cons**

#### Separate domains (example.de, example.fr, etc)

**Pros:** Clear geotargeting, server location is irrelevant, easy separation of sites, legal requirements (sometimes)

**Cons:** Expensive (+ availability), more infrastructure, ccTLD requirements (sometimes)

---

#### Sub domains (de.site.com, fr.site.com, etc)

**Pros:** Easy to set up, can use Webmaster Tools geotargeting, allows different server locations, easy separation of sites

**Cons:**: Users might not recognize geotargeting from the URL alone (is "de" the language or country?)

---

#### Sub folders (site.com/de/, site.com/fr/, etc)

**Pros:**: Easy to set up, can use Webmaster Tools geotargeting, low maintenance (same host)

**Cons:**: Users might not recognize geotargeting from the URL alone, single server location, separation of sites harder